# Disable ViewFormPagesLockdown feature without PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

Is there any manual way to disable `ViewFormPagesLockdown` feature for any particular list in SharePoint 2013 publishing website.

I don't want to use PowerShell because in PowerShell it's the following errors:

> Get-SPFeature -site http://url//-Identity ViewFormPagesLockdown
>   Get-SPFeature : The term 'Get-SPFeature' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
>   spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again

If anyone knows how to disable this feature manually kindly tell me

Answer (score 1):

You need to use it as below in powershell:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell

$lockdown = Get-spfeature ViewFormPagesLockdown

disable-spfeature $lockdown -url http://sitecollectionURL
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.

but I want to disable it without powershell, is it posible? if yes then can you please guide me how to perform that??

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code to deactivate feature. You just need to add the sharepoint snapin and it will work

Comment: Dear brother still i'm getting the same error:
PS C:\Users\a.> Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell

 get-spfeature-site http://sharepoint.dd.net
get-spfeature-site : The term 'get-spfeature-site' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. 
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:4 char:2
+  get-spfeature-site http://sharepoint.dd.net
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~